# Undefined Json response from django backend to chrome extension alert

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, google-chrome-extension

Hi i am trying to return a json file to  the chrome extention to show it to the user, the query go to server without a problem, fetched url is also working and does return the json file when i try it directly, but the chrome extention shows `"undefined"` message in the alert instead of the json file.

the returned json file have this type : `JsonResponse(data)`

data is a `dict[str, Union[str, list]]`,

another question, is how can I show the json file in the popup html page?

to my chrome extension code:

Manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "Price Comparator",
  "description": "Compare prices across other websites!",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "images/logo16.png",
    "48": "images/logo48.png",
    "128": "images/logo128.png"
  },
  "action": {
    "default_icon": "images/logo16.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "host_permissions": ["XXX*"],
  "permissions": [
    "XXX",
    "http://127.0.0.1:8000/",
    "storage",
    "activeTab",
    "scripting",
    "tabs",
    "background",
    "identity",
    "notifications"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "https://www.google.com/*"
      ],
      "css": [
        "main.css"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

popup.js:

```
$(function(){

    
    $('#keywordsubmit').click(function(){
        
        var search_topic = $('#keyword').val();
        
                
        if (search_topic){
                chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
                    {topic: search_topic},
                    function(response) {
                        result = response.farewell;
                        alert(result.summary);
                        
                        var notifOptions = {
                            type: "basic",
                            iconUrl: "icon48.png",
                            title: "WikiPedia Summary For Your Result",
                        };
                        chrome.notifications.create('WikiNotif', notifOptions);
                        
                    });
        }
            
            
        $('#keyword').val('');
        
    });
});
```

Background.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => { console.log('Extension is running!'); });

chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function (activeInfo) {
    chrome.tabs.get(activeInfo.tabId, function (tab) {
        y = tab.url;
        console.log("you are here: " + tab.title);
    });
});

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, change, tab) => {
    if (tab.active && change.url) {
        console.log("you are here: " + change.url);
    }
});

var serverhost = 'XXXX';

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function (request, sender, sendResponse) {


        var url = serverhost + '/wiki/get_wiki_summary/?topic=' + encodeURIComponent(request.topic);

        console.log(url);

        //var url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/wiki/get_wiki_summary/?topic=%22COVID19%22"  
        fetch(url)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(response => sendResponse({ farewell: response }))
            .catch(error => console.log(error))
        return true;  // Will respond asynchronously.

    });
```

here is the python code:

```
  def get_wiki_summary(request):
query = request.GET.get('topic', None) +" XXXX"

user_agent_list = [
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.1.1 Safari/605.1.15',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36',
]
for i in range(1, 4):
    user_agent = random.choice(user_agent_list)

headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent}

## Google Search query results as a Python List of URLs
search_result_list = list(search(query, tld="de", num=1, stop=1, pause=1))

page = requests.get(search_result_list[0], headers=headers)
time.sleep(4)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "lxml")

with open("output1.html", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    file.write(str(soup))

if soup.findAll(text="captcha") :
    return JsonResponse(search_result_list[0])


else:
    data = parsefile()

    return JsonResponse(data)
```

and the parse function:

```
def parsefile():
Productimage = {}

Products = {}
Images = {}
print(Products)
# Products = defaultdict(list)

with open('output1.html', 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    html_string = f.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_string, 'lxml')
prices = soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'productOffers-listItemOfferPrice'})

for elem in prices:
    oldlink = elem['href']
    elem['href'] = ("http://XXXX.de" + oldlink)
    # oldlink = requests.get(elem['href'])
    # print(oldlink.url)
    # elem['href']  = oldlink.headers['Location']
    # domain = urlparse(oldlink.url).netloc

    if "Website" not in Products:
        Products["Website"] = list()
    if "Link" not in Products:
        Products["Link"] = list()
    if "Price" not in Products:
        Products["Price"] = list()

    Products["Website"].append(elem['href'])
    Products["Price"].append(str((elem.get_text())))
    Products["Link"].append(elem['href'])

listimage = soup.find('img', {'class': 'datasheet-cover-image'})

if "Image" not in Images:
    Products["Image"] = str(listimage.get("src"))
data = {
    'summary': str(listimage.get("src")),
    'raw': 'Successful',

}

with open("prices.html", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    file.write(str(prices))

with open('resultproducts.json', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as fp:
    json.dump(Products, fp)

return Products
```

Comment: maybe use `alert()` or `console.log()` to see what you really have in other variables. Maybe you send request to wrong URL, or you skip some element.

Comment: where is code which sends JSON to browser?

Comment: if I understand you get `undefined` with `alert(result.summary);` but maybe your result doesn't have `.summary`. Did you check what you get with `response.json()` ? Maybe it gets corrent JSON from server but later you try to get wrong value.

Comment: When i send a json response of a dict of this type [str,str], it does show up, but the response that i want to see have this type dict[str, Union[str, list]], in this case i get undefined in the alert

Comment: I think JavaScript doesn't care what you send. Type of data can be important only in Python but you didn't show Python code. You should run it console to see if it get error. You could also use `print()` to see what you really send. You can also use Python `requests` to send request to Django and see what you get in response.

Comment: Thank for the feedback, like i meantionned in the main text, the result of json that does no show up in the alert notification in chrome extention, i can see it in python using that GET link "var url = serverhost + '/wiki/get_wiki_summary/?topic=' + encodeURIComponent(request.topic); " without a problem 
, but in the alert i see undefined

Comment: also do you mean the console in chrome or in python, because in python i dod not really see any error in console, in python like i mentionned there are no problems

Comment: for `print()` I mean system console/terminal/bash/powershell/cmd.exe, for `console.log()` I mean JavaScript console in Chrome (`DevTools`). But you should always check both.

Comment: all your problem can be in Python code - it may send wrong response - but you didn't show Python code. It doesn't matter what you send in url from browser to Python/Django but what you send from Python/Django to browser.

Comment: I have added my python code, the response from django to browser is the one that i am seeing correctly when i open directly the link, but in the chrome alert it does show that undefined error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All problem is in Python code.

In JavaScript you want to display `summary`

```
alert(result.summary);
```

and in Python in `parsefile()` you create

```
data = {
    'summary': str(listimage.get("src")),
    'raw': 'Successful',
}
```

but later you send `Product` instead of `data`

```
return Product
```

so your

```
data = parsefile()

return JsonResponse(data)
```

means

```
return JsonResponse(Product)
```

instead of

```
return JsonResponse({
           'summary': str(listimage.get("src")),
           'raw': 'Successful',
       })
```

In `parsefile()` you should do

```
return data
```

or

```
Product['summary'] = str(listimage.get("src"))
Product['raw'] = 'Successful'

return Product
```

Comment: i created that data dict just for testing purposes, the thing that i want to send is products, and if you noticed Products does get filled in that for loop and also after that with the image

Comment: I think i got you, in the alert i wanted to show the key called summary , there are no such key in Products dict, Thank you for making that clear